# Increase timeout for gradle to get a maven dependency

Tags: maven, grails, gradle, grails-3.1

I am tring to get a jar dependency from Maven via the `grails 3.1.5` **gradle dependency Resolution** . How do I increase timeout that gradle takes to get a maven dependency. Sure I have seen that the dependency takes quiet a longer time to be downloaded. But how can I configure gradle to wait longer in order to download the dependency

Comment: What do you mean to get a dependency from Maven? Do you mean a Maven Central repository or an internal repository manager ?

Comment: An internal archiva repo

Answer (score 41):

The feature was added in Gradle here:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/3041

You can increase the timeout with 2 properties:

```
./gradlew build -Dhttp.socketTimeout=60000 -Dhttp.connectionTimeout=60000
```

As commented by Sue C, If you are using gradle 4.10.2 or later version use following [properties](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/f2fd5f4209735e34905c321c43309d03850cf98a#diff-74c3ade11e986620589ba9ac0d78dcef):

`./gradlew build -Dorg.gradle.internal.http.socketTimeout=60000 -Dorg.gradle.internal.http.connectionTimeout=60000`

Comment: As of gradle version 4.10.2 these properties changed their names to
`org.gradle.internal.http.connectionTimeout` and `org.gradle.internal.http.socketTimeout`
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/f2fd5f4209735e34905c321c43309d03850cf98a#diff-74c3ade11e986620589ba9ac0d78dcef

Comment: I believe Sue C's comment applies not only to 4.10.2+, but to 4.3.1+ (see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/3371).  I know this is true for 4.10, which is what I'm currently using.

Comment: It works for me: `-Phttp.socketTimeout=200000 -Phttp.connectionTimeout=200000`  with Gradle 4.8.1 version

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I was hitting the same Java read timeout issue with Gradle 7.5 and Java 17, and this is the top search result returned.

I was running an existing `gradlew` wrapper script on a new machine and consistently getting this:

```
./gradlew build
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
...........10%............20%...........30%............40%...........50%............60%...........70%............80%...........90%............
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Downloading from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip failed: timeout
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:110)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:67)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:68)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:288)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:314)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:355)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:808)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:976)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:484)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1465)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1069)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:282)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:141)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3711)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3704)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:93)
    ... 7 more
```

Adding  `-Dhttp.socketTimeout=60000 -Dhttp.connectionTimeout=60000` didn't help, it always timed out after 10 seconds (seems like a rate limit on that server, but that's a separate issue).

I read that those timeout settings applied to both http and https. But it turns out that's not true, changing `http` to `https` worked:

```
./gradlew build -Dhttps.socketTimeout=60000 -Dhttps.connectionTimeout=60000
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
...........10%............20%...........30%............40%...........50%............60%...........70%............80%...........90%............100%

Welcome to Gradle 7.5!
...
```

Comment: Since 2022-06-08, there is a more user-friendly incubating (~experimental) property: `-PnetworkTimeout=...`. Documentation: <https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper:networkTimeout>; GitHub PR: <https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/20504>.