# Android Gradle Read timed out

Tags: android, gradle

In one of my android projects when i build the project, I sometimes get the following Error!! :

```
Read timed out
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
```

I don't know why but it built ok most of the times. How can i fix this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47607857/6016830 may help!

Comment: @buzzingsilently thanks, but i checked it before asking this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is network, maybe you have some gradle or maven repositories in your Gradle file that get timeout when you build or run project. if you have so, comment it whenever you get this error and build again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the Read Time Out error, then enabled gradle offline mode and could build again whitout problems